# JS Include inside included .php file

Tags: php

I have included a PHP file on my mainpage, inside the php file there's another include of  a .js file, the included php file is in a different directory than the mainpage, so the included .js file can't be found.

To visualize:

- Mainpage - Root
- Included PHP file -File A located in Folder A
- Included JS file in File A is located in Folder A

But it's looking for the .js file in Root instead of Folder A

How do I get the path right ?

Also it should be dynamic, I might not know the actual name of Folder A

Comment: Look up relative and absolute URLs

Comment: Thanks  `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is what I was looking for. Still the folder name is missing, I don't want to set it manually, as the folder name might not be the same everytime. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .. notation to traverse folders

the path would be `'../script.js'`

Comment: It depends where he's accessing the php from.

Comment: I'm trying to go into a folder, not out of it, also I don't know the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Site:
www.yoursite.com

Folders:

- /index.php
- /lib/header.php
- /contacts/index.php
- /js/main.js

Let's say you want to inclue your /js/main.js file inside /lib/header.php in order to work wherever you include /lib/header.php, for example in /index.php and /contacts/index.php.

You would have the following inside /lib/header.php :

```
<script src="http://www.yoursite.com/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if  include.php and xyz.js are in the same directory. than

include .js file in include.php like that--

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="xyz.js"></script>
```

if it is not working than u should use Relative Url/SITE URL like that--

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://localhost/folder/xyz.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am infact including it like `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="xyz.js"></script>` but he's looking in the root folder rather than folder A

Comment: ok. than you should use relative url. first tell me, are you working on live or localhost?